# Using AngularJS service not getting the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If i access the link http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl?action=GET
I will get this data:

```
[{"name":"Baby Care","id":"2","image":"/images/categories/baby-care.png"},{"name":" Bread, Bakery & Dairy Products","id":"5","image":"/images/categories/dairy-products.png"},{"name":"Beverages","id":"6","image":"/images/categories/beverages.png"},{"name":"Others","id":"9","image":"/images/categories/others.png"}]
```

But when i try to get the same data using AngularJS service and controller, I m not getting the data. This is my controller and service code.

```
sampleApp.factory('SuperCategoryService', ['$http', function ($http){
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: { action: 'GET' }
};  

  return {
        GetSuperCategories: function () {
            return $http(req).then(

                function(response) 
                {
                    if (typeof response === 'object') 
                    {
                        return response;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        alert ('wrong');
                    }
                },
                function(response) {
                    alert ('again worng');
                    // something went wrong
                    //return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
            }
        };
}]);

sampleApp.controller('SuperCategoryController', function ($scope,SuperCategoryService) {

    $scope.SuperCategories = [];

    $scope.GetSuperCategories = function() {

        SuperCategoryService.GetSuperCategories().then(
        function(d) {
            alert (d);
            if (d !== undefined) {
                alert ('in');
                console.log(d);
                $scope.SuperCategories = d;
            }
            else  {
                alert ('undefined data');
            }
        },

        function(response) {
            alert ('error worng');
            // something went wrong
            //return $q.reject(response.data);
        });

    };

    $scope.GetSuperCategories();
});
```

though code is reaching to alert ('in'), but nothing is getting assigned to variable $scope.SuperCategories;

Can some one help me what i m doing wrong in assignment.

Comment: Are both running in `localhost`? Do you see anything like `Allow Origin CORS` error in browser console?

Comment: What is the value of `d` printed to the console?

Comment: Is it a `GET` or `POST` request? You've mentioned that when you try to access the link , you're getting the response which looks like `GET` request whereas in service you've mentioned it as `POST` request. Also `POST` request will not add `?action=GET` to URL

Comment: Yes both running in localhost. There is no such error Allow Origin CORS

Comment: Its reaching 2 times to print (d) in console. I don't know why? Values its printing is   Object {data: "", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}
Object {data: "", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}

Comment: have you tried running it in firefox?

Comment: I tried in both the browsers (chrome and firefox)

Comment: @mohamedrias; then how to add ?action=GET in URL? Can you please help.

Comment: In your service, just return the promise. Don't try to resolve the promise in your service, just return it: `return $http.(req);` Call the `.then()` method in  the controller, not the service.

Answer (score 1):

Your service function is doing `$http` using `.then` which is nothing but resolving using chain promise you should get explicit data from object you service will return `response.data` instead of `response`

```
   GetSuperCategories: function () {
        return $http(req).then(

            function(response) 
            {
                var data = response.data;
                if (typeof data === 'object') 
                {
                    return data ;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    alert ('wrong');
                }
            },
            function(response) {
                alert ('again worng');
                // something went wrong
                //return $q.reject(response.data);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. it is reaching to alert ('wrong') now.

Comment: could you add `console.log(data)` right after `var data = response.data;`

Comment: Its blank. variable named data is not holding anything. so its printing blank line.

Comment: Ahhh.. Its wiered..what does your response object contain?

Comment: console.log(response) gives: Object {data: "", status: 200, headers: function, config: Object}

Comment: Your service is returning blank string then how can it work..As per I suggested..code is working fine..and alerting `alert("wrong")` as it `data` doesn't contain object

Comment: Yes that's true. But why service is returning blank. As i mentioned "http://localhost/cgi-bin/superCategory.pl?action=GET" in browser gives - [{"name":"Baby Care","id":"2","image":"/images/categories/baby-care.png"},{"name":" Bread, Bakery & Dairy Products","id":"5","image":"/images/categories/dairy-products.png"},{"name":"Beverages","id":"6","image":"/images/categories/beverages.png"},{"name":"Others","id":"9","image":"/images/categories/others.png"}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74130/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-devesh-agrawal).

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal you could do upvote..if it does helped you. Thanks